# SQL-запрос. Выбрать компании в которых состоят только пользователи, не привязанные к другим компаниям

Tags: sql

[image: Таблица]

Есть такая таблица, необходимо составить Sql-запрос, чтоб выбрать компании в которых состоят только(!) пользователи, не привязанные к другим компаниям.
Перепробовал все, что только знаю и зашёл в тупик. Если у вас есть варианты или хотя бы направление куда думать - буду рад почитать. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте самосоединение таблиц на условии ``t1.user_id=t2.use_id and t1.company_id<>t2.company_id``

Comment: Увы, не совсем то, но спасибо за мысль, попробую её ещё как-то развернуть

Comment: Типичная задача на NOT EXISTS / LEFT JOIN WHERE IS NULL / WHERE NOT IN. А если `(company_id, user_id)` уникальна, то есть ещё и вариант с группировкой. Впрочем, COUNT(DISTINCT) возможен в любом случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно такой вариант

```
select company_id
from(
  select company_id
     ,count(*)over(partition by user_id) ucnt
  from t
)x
group by company_id
having max(ucnt)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, найти сколько компаний имеется у каждого пользователя и отфильтровать те компании, у которых *у всех пользователей* максимальное число компаний равно одному:

```sql
select company_id
from (
  select t.company_id, t.user_id, t2.cc
  from t
  join (
    select user_id, count(*) cc -- подсчет количества компаний по пользователю
    from t
    group by user_id
  ) t2 on t.user_id = t2.user_id
) res
group by company_id
having max(cc) = 1
```

результат [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f7150/11):

```
3
5
```